# is it possible to query in mongoose with excluding / ingore string option

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am not too sure how to explain within few words at the title.
Please let me know if there's suggestion to make the title easier to understand.

Anyways, what I want to ask is, I am trying to query by phone number in db BUT the phone number in db has two different styles one is with dash and one without

So in db the phone field might be

```
{phone: '1234567890'}
{phone: '123-456-1111'}
```

When a user is trying to search for a number, user might enter the full 10 digits `1234561111` or `123-456-1111`.  For sure I can replace all dash in `123-456-1111` and make it `1234561111`.

But then `1234561111`  would still not match what the db to query it out though.

What are the ways I can get this query to work though.
Currently using `mongoose` to do the query.

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions.

Comment: You can use $or to search in both way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not wrong you want to search for "1234567890" in db where the phone might be "123-456-7890" or "1234567890". So there are two techniques.

**First one is :** Search by regex. This will match both "123-456-7890" and "1234567890".

```
db.test.find({phone: /123\-?456\-?7890/})
```

**Second:** If you don't want to tamper with the search string, the Solution is using aggregation.

For MongoDB 4.4

```
db.test.aggregate([
{
    $addFields: {
        extractedPhone: { $replaceAll: { input: "$phone", find: "-", replacement: "" } }
    }
},
{
    $match: {
        extractedPhone: "1234567890"
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        extractedPhone: 0
    }
}
])
```

For Older version of MongoDB

```
db.test.aggregate([
{
    $addFields: {
        extractedPhone: {
            $reduce: {
              input: { $split: ["$phone", "-"]},
              initialValue: '',
              in: {
                $concat: ['$$value', '$$this']
              }
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    $match: {
        extractedPhone: "1234567890"
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        extractedPhone: 0
    }
}
])
```

Comment: I do not have the repo to give it a try yet until next week but this does seem like what I need though :D let me give it a try next week.  But then I have more fields for the query do I just add it into the `$match` for example `$match {extractedPhone: "1234567890", name: { $regex: new RegExp(\`^${name}$\`, "i") }}`

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Just add them in the $match. But remember one thing we've used the $match stage after $addFields just because we didn't have the modified phone field. Its good practice to use $match as early as possible in the pipeline to speedup the pipeline. 
And let me know if it works or not. :)

Comment: Seems to be working perfectly, not able to try the new version since mine is 4.2 :D thanks thanks